# Drag and resize UIImage (OSX)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, resize, drag

i am very new to objective-c, but i want to make some app that does the following:

1 It has object library (shapes, text fields and so on), i keep in on a panel on my app.
  - the task is to drag a shape to the main form and place it somewhere where i like on my form: kind of same thing like in the Interface builder.

2 resize the shape (Actually an UIIMage).

It's pretty same with the Interface builder.

I would very appreciate for any example code that helps me to solve this task.

EDIT:
Exactly the same but for iOS exists here:
https://github.com/spoletto/SPUserResizableView

As i can see in the code it's not very easy task so this question is considered answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by checking this out:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/DragItemAround/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Seems there are normal people here. Thanks for the link. Would appreciate if you can point me to an example where i could resize an object using mouse.